# Salesforce Filtering 24 Clock Issue

Tags: reporting, formula, datetime

This may seem quite simple, but I am unable to filter correctly by certain times. Filtering "Starts with 1" or "starts with 2" for 1am or 2am will also filter any time beginning with 1 or 2 e.g. 12.00 or 20.00.

Can anybody suggest a better to filter? I am using the created date field in a formula to show only the time:

```
IF(
ISBLANK(CreatedDate),"0",
TEXT(MOD(VALUE(
Left(
right( trim(TEXT(CreatedDate) ),9),2))+2,24))
&":"&mid(right( trim(TEXT(CreatedDate) ),9),4,2)
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just extract the time from the CreatedDate field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TIMEVALUE()` formula to display a time from a DateTime Field. So `TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)` is all you need.